# Spring Boot: error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wrote a very Spring boot simple app.

To get the authentication token, I used the following `curl` command. But instead I see the following error in the server log (eclipse console): `error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"`

```
curl -v -u greetings:123456 -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "username=username&password=password&grant_type=password&scope=write&client_secret=12345&client_id=greetings"
```

I wonder:

What have I done wrong that it doesn't let me get the `auth code`?

`OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    String applicationName = "greetings";

    // This is required for password grants, which we specify below as one of the
    // {@literal authorizedGrantTypes()}.
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // Workaround for https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1801
        endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
                    throws AuthenticationException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(applicationName)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER")
            .scopes("write")
            .resourceIds(applicationName)
            .secret("123456");
    }
}
```

`WebSecurityConfiguration.java`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import com.boot.myproj.repository.AccountRepository;

class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> userRepository
                .findByUsername(username)
                .map(a -> new User(a.username, a.password, true, true, true, true,
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER", "write")))
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '"
                                + username + "'"));
    }
}
```

`Account.java`

```
import javax.persistence.*;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String password;
    public String username;

    public Account(String name, String password) {
        this.username = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Account() { // jpa only
    }
}
```

`AccountRepository.java`

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.boot.myproj.config.security.Account;

public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String>{
    public Optional<Account> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

`App.java`

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.boot.cut_costs.config.security.Account;
import com.boot.cut_costs.repository.AccountRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        return (arg) -> {
            accountRepository.save(new Account("username", "password"));
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to do here with password grant will not return an "auth code" , instead it'll directly return you a accessToken.

Comment: Your client secret is "123456" and in your URL you're passing "12345". Change it and see what happens

Comment: I think you should add `@Configuration` to `WebSecurityConfiguration` class. So that your bean will get injected in spring context.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `@Configuration` to `WebSecurityConfiguration` class. So that your bean will get injected in spring context.

p.s. What you are trying to do here with `OAuth2 password grant` will not return an **auth code** , instead it'll directly return you a **accessToken**.